# CSS li:before statement deactivates html links in list item

Tags: html, css

The header of my script looks like this:

```css
.tickList {
  margin: -0.5em 0.5em;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

.tickList li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: -1.5em;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  margin-left: -3.5em;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}

.tickList li:before {
  display: block;
  content: "\27A5";
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #41845B;
  position: relative;
  left: -1.1em;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tickList">
  <li>Some text <a href="somelink">link text</a>. More text.</li>
</ul>
```

Now, if I look at my page in a browser, the link text is underlined and looks like a link, however, if I move my mouse over it, the cursor does not change and clicking on it has no effect. I did some testing and it turns out that if I remove the `.ticklist li:before` part from the style declarations (or just the `display:block` part actually), then the link works as expected. Why does this bit of CSS code break the link functionality?

Note that I am not including any outside js packages like jQuery or anything else.

Comment: `display: block` will make the element fill 100 percent of its parent's width. The `:before` element is also higher in the stacking context (`z-index`) than its parent, so it's covering the entire `li` contents. Set a `z-index: -1`  if you need to keep the `display: block` or set `pointer-events: none` on the `:before` element

Comment: @disinfor I agree with your marked duplicate, the problem is that there is no explanation of what's going on, such as your first comment above. Maybe you want to comment there also, or even edit the accepted answer to explain what the issue is?

Comment: @disinfor The entire list is part of a more complex div structure so I need the display block. But the ```pointer-events: none``` did solve the issue. As did setting a fixed width of 50px as suggested by Weliton. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width of your `:before` element is actually 100% of the page, try defining a fixed width, and you'll see the overlay won't show anymore.

```css
.tickList li:before {
  display: block;
  content: "\27A5";
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #41845B;
  position: relative;
  left: -1.1em;
  top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

something like that

Answer (score 0):

The same result could have been achieved with less struggle:

```css
.tickList {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.tickList li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.tickList li:before {
  content: "\27A5";
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #41845B;
  position: relative;
  top: .15em;
  padding-right: .2em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tickList">
  <li>Some text <a href="somelink">link text</a>. More text.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I do need the ```display: block``` as the list is part of a more complex div structure and the layout breaks without it.

Answer (score -1):

There are a variety of ways to fix the issue, which is the inserted before element is sitting on top of the list item. Try adding [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to your before rules. This will prevent the before element from being the target of any pointer events, essentially passing it down through to the list item:

```css
.tickList {
  margin: -0.5em 0.5em;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

.tickList li {
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: -1.5em;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  margin-left: -3.5em;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}

.tickList li:before {
  display: block;
  content: "\27A5";
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #41845B;
  position: relative;
  left: -1.1em;
  top: 25px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tickList">
  <li>Some text <a href="somelink">link text</a>. More text.</li>
</ul>
```

Alternately you could also set the z-index of the before element to -1 which effectively moves it behind the page.

Comment: This works. Thank you. Unfortunately I can only choose 1 solution.